# How to read depth sensor data from Orbbec Astra Pro using Emgu.CV?

Tags: opencv, emgucv, orbbec

I am trying to read from the depth sensor of my Orbbec Astra Pro camera which is connected to a Windows 10 Pro machine.

I am using Emgu.CV and have installed the camera driver downloaded via the link `Download Orbbec Sensor Driver for Windows` as shown in the screenshot below. Its very unclear to me which packages/components are required. So far I was able to read from the RGB sensor.

However how in the world can I access the UCV stream / depth sensor data? I was assuming the depth sensor forms a device at its own, which theirfor can be accessed like being the second camera in my system.

```
var rgbSensor = new VideoCapture(0)
var uvcSensor = new VideoCapture(1)
```

This however seems not to work. Is OpeNI2 required to get depth sensor data?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you need OpenNI

Comment: Thanks for replying. I still don't get the depdencies here. Will I be able to get depth images from the camera by using e.g. an OpenNI C# wrapper like `NiWrapper` or `Nimble`? Or does Orbbec provide a modified version of OpenNI?

Comment: you just add your OpenNI dlls to your c# project references

Comment: How do you translate pixel value to distance in  mm from the Mat object?